# correct way to conditionally filter within dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(041019)
```

I have defined a simple function that adds 2 columns together such as in this example:

```
# data    
dat <- data.frame("x" = sample(1:100, 10), "y" = sample(1:100, 10))

# define function
addXY <- function(dat) {
 datOut <- dat %>%
 mutate(z = x + y)
 return(datOut)
}

addXY(dat)

    x  y   z
1  80 30 110
2  28 16  44
3  11 61  72
4  37 24  61
5  29 44  73
6  62 33  95
7  94 50 144
8  59 59 118
9  88 39 127
10 65 78 143
```

Say I want to add a binary argument to this function and use it to conditionally filter within a dplyr chain. How would i correctly do this. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
addXY <- function(dat, aboveFifty = TRUE) {
  datOut -> dat %>%
    if (!aboveFifty) {filter(x < 50)} else {filter(x <= 100)} %>%
    mutate(z = x + y)
    return(datOut)
}
addXY(dat, aboveFifty = FALSE)
```

Fails with error message:

```
Error in if (.) !aboveFifty else { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (.) !aboveFifty else { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

It looks like it is trying to filter the argument and not the data, which is obviously not what I want.

Comment: Typo, edited now.

Comment: It's not currently clear where/what `dat` is being piped in to.  You can work around this be wrapping the whole statement in curly braces and using dots in `filter()`.  Like `dat %>% {if (!aboveFifty) {filter(., x < 50)} else {filter(., x <= 100)} }`

Comment: nice one. That works. Thanks

Comment: Since you've already got this filtering operation in a function, you can add an assignment to a threshold variable, then filter based on that

Answer (score 2):

You can put an `if` statement in your `filter`:

```
addXY <- function(x, aboveFifty = T) x %>%
  filter(if (aboveFifty) x < 50 else x < 100) %>%
  mutate(z = x + y)

addXY(dat)

   x  y  z
1 28 16 44
2 11 61 72
3 37 24 61
4 29 44 73
```